# Determine where a function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Define the function

$$f(z) = \frac{z^2+iz-1-2i}{z+1}$$

Determine where the function is holomorphic.

---

The answer provided is:

> We note that $f$ is differentiable for any $z\not=-1$ hence is holomorphic on the domain $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1\}$.

This has just been stated but how do we know this? I understand the derivative

$$f'(z) = \frac{(\cdots)}{(x+1)^2}$$

so are we simply looking at where the derivative blows up?

Comment: A function is holomorphic on $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ if it is differentiable everywhere on an open set containing $A$. So you're looking to find $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ such that the limit of the difference quotient does not exist when $z\to z_0$, i.e. where the function fails to be differentiable. Does $\lim_{z\to -1} \frac{f(z)-f(-1)}{z-(-1)}$ exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard calculus formulas for derivatives of $f+g$, $f-g$, $f g$, $f/g$ are valid everywhere $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, with the exception that for $f/g$ you need to avoid points where $ g=0$.  At such points $f/g$ is undefined, and thus of course not differentiable.

Answer (score 4):

There's just barely any difference between "holomorphic" and "differentiable".  The function $z\mapsto|z|^2\vphantom{\tfrac\int1}$ is differentiable (only) at $0$, but is nowhere holomorphic because there is no open set at every point of which it is differentiable.

Your function is a polynomial over a polynomial. If you know that polynomials are differentiable everywhere, then you can say that by the quotient rule, the quotient is differentiable except where the denominator is $0$.  The denominator is $0$ at only one point, and the complement of that is an open set, so it is holomorphic on that open set.